# Gatsby site, Script not available on first page request with Helmet

Tags: javascript, gatsby, helmet.js

I have a Gatsby site that I'm trying to add a third-party js widget to but for some strange reason it will only load if I refresh the page manually. On first page load, it as is if it doesn't exist at all, no errors in dev-tools, nothing... but if I refresh the page, it then appears. It's almost as if it's lazy loading? Is there a way to force load?

I've checked the `elements`, `console`, and `network` tabs in dev tools but there's nothing to indicate any errors. `elements` shows the tags that I would expect, `console` shows nothing at all, and `network` everything shows up with 200.

Could this be an issue with Gatsby and/or Helmet, it might be but I don't think it's an issue with the widget itself (it's third-party, I have no control over it, see last paragraph)?

```
<Helmet
    script={[
        {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            src: '//widget-url.com/path/to/jsfile.min.js',
        },
        {
            type: 'text/javascript',
            innerHTML: `
               (function() {
                   var widget = Stuff.happens.here();
                   widget.Initialise();
                })();
            `,
        },
    ]}
/>
```

In the body I then have:

```
<div id='widget-id'></div>
```

**Things I've tried to attempt to understand where the issue is**:

- As I mentioned, I have to force refresh the page where the widget is located. If I force refresh any other page, it doesn't help. So something I tried is: rather than only including the JS into the head of the page in question, I would including it on ALL pages. But this has made no difference.
- I've also tried adding the widget to a simple stand-alone html file, the widget loads without problem. Which leads me to think that it's probably not a widget issue?

I don't know where to go from here :(

Comment: Is the widget code executed automatically? Or do you have to invoke it manually, something like `widget.init()`?

Comment: @Akshay automatically, it's supposed to just display a little calendar.

Comment: See if the widget provides a way to invoke it manually. If it does call it inside a `useEffect` from that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pointing a DOM element that may or may not be rendered at the moment your request the script.

In your case, I'd try:

```
<Helmet>
    <script async defer src="//widget-url.com/path/to/jsfile.min.js" />
    <script async defer>
     {`
      (function() {
          var widget = Stuff.happens.here();
           widget.Initialise();
         })();   
      `}
    </script>
</Helmet>
```

Or using one of the multiple Server-Side Rendering APIs. [`onRenderBody`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/) should work:

```
// gatsby-ssr.js
import React from "react"
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents, setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script 
      src="//widget-url.com/path/to/jsfile.min.js"
      type="text/javascript"
      async
    />,
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `
        (function() {
         var widget = Stuff.happens.here();
          widget.Initialise();
        })();   
     `,
    }}
   />, 
 ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this makes a lot of sense. But I did forget one piece of JS (question updated: I added the `innerHTML` block which initialises the script) and I can't seem to figure out how do I add that that block.

Comment: I've edited the answer adding the inner script. Check the quotation because it's tricky using markdown